# Why can't Ant find javac?

Tags: java, windows, ant, build, ibatis

There is the following `build.bat` file:

```
echo off  
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"  
set BUILD_CP="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\lib\tools.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin";..\devlib\ant.jar;..\devlib\optional.jar;..\devlib\junit.jar;..\devlib\xercesImpl.jar;..\devlib\xmlParserAPIs.jar;  
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java" -classpath %BUILD_CP% org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml all  

set BUILD_CP=  

pause
```

When I run it I get:

BUILD FAILED

```
file:D:/Development/Java/Frameworks/JMeter/TestDemoIbatis/iBATIS_JPetStore-4.0.5/build/build.xml:29: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK

Total time: 0 seconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But my `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` is properly [set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCEhH.png):

[image]

**Update:**
The ant script:

```
<project name="JPetStore" default="all" basedir=".">  

  <property file="build.properties"/>  

  <path id="classpath">  
    <pathelement location="${src}/"/>  
    <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />  
    <fileset dir="${devlib}" includes="**/*.jar" />  
  </path>  

  <target name="clean" >  
    <delete dir="${wars}"/>  
    <delete dir="${webapp}"/>  
    <delete>  
      <fileset dir="${src}" >  
        <include name="**/*.class"/>  
      </fileset>  
    </delete>  
  </target>  

  <target name="prepare" depends="clean">  
    <mkdir dir="${wars}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${webapp}"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/classes"/>  
    <mkdir dir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/lib"/>  
  </target>  

  <target name="compile" depends="prepare"> //LINE 29 that fails 
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/classes" deprecation="off" debug="${debug}">  
      <classpath refid="classpath"/>  
    </javac>  
  </target>  

  <target name="assemble.view">  
    <copy todir="${webapp}">  
      <fileset dir="${web}">  
        <include name="**/*.jsp"/>  
        <include name="**/*.html"/>  
      </fileset>  

    </copy>  
  </target>  

  <target name="assemble" depends="compile">  
    <copy todir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/classes">  
      <fileset dir="${src}" >  
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>  
        <exclude name="**/*.class"/>  
      </fileset>  
    </copy>  
    <copy todir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/lib">  
      <fileset dir="${lib}" />  
    </copy>  
    <copy todir="${webapp}">  
      <fileset dir="${web}" />  
    </copy>  
  </target>  

  <target name="war" depends="assemble">  
    <jar jarfile="${wars}/jpetstore.war">  
      <fileset dir="${webapp}">  
        <include name="**/*"/>  
      </fileset>  
    </jar>  
  </target>  

  <target name="all" depends="war" />  

</project>
```

What is the problem here? I am in `Windows7/64-bit`

Comment: Are you using fork="yes" in your javac target in the ant script?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani:Updated OP

Comment: @OdedPeer:There is no fork and it is not my script.It is from `Ibatis`(http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibatisjpetstore/)

Comment: Why the downvote?Am I doing something **obviously** wrong?What?

Comment: This is not a normal way of calling ant to perform a build.  Why not call the ant batch file from your batch script and use the ant build file for setting up the classpath?

Comment: @Chris:This how `build.bat` was inside the `ibatis` demo project I donwloaded.And the `bat` file calls `org.apache.tools.ant.Main`.Could you specify exactly how you suggest to change these scripts?

Comment: Can you please share the contents of build.properties?

Comment: Follow the logic of the ant javac task here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.7.0/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/compilers/CompilerAdapter.java#CompilerAdapter it might lead you to a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just worked for me:

```
echo off

set JAVA_HOME="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"

set BUILD_CP=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;..\devlib\ant.jar;..\devlib\optional.jar;..\devlib\junit.jar;..\devlib\xercesImpl.jar;..\devlib\xmlParserAPIs.jar;

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %BUILD_CP% org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml all

set BUILD_CP=

pause
```

Note that I had to change the build.xml to add the source=1.4 directive:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${webapp}/WEB-INF/classes" deprecation="off" debug="${debug}" source="1.4">
```

Comment: You are right about the `source`.I also encountered it when I run the build directly

Answer (score 1):

Try putting double quotes around the classpath to prevent the classpath being split up due to the spaces:

From this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java" -classpath %BUILD_CP% org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml all
```

To

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java" -classpath "%BUILD_CP%" org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml all
```

**Edit:**

You could also try removing the quotes from the BUILD_CP.

```
echo off  
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"  
set BUILD_CP=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;..\devlib\ant.jar;..\devlib\optional.jar;..\devlib\junit.jar;..\devlib\xercesImpl.jar;..\devlib\xmlParserAPIs.jar;  
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java" -classpath "%BUILD_CP%" org.apache.tools.ant.Main -buildfile build.xml all  

set BUILD_CP=  

pause
```

Comment: I guess another option would be to try installing the JDK in a folder that doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: Why would I do that?I never had issues.If this is some `Windows 7` issue and there is a reference recommending it, I would do it

Comment: @Cratylus Have you tried with this `C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_25` ?

Comment: @Polppan:I get:`The system cannot find the path specified.`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some sort of issue with the spaces in `Program Files`.
Following @Chris comment I tried to build the file myself and noticed that `ant -p` failed due to `""` in the environmental variables.
By making `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25` from `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"` I was able to run `ant` directly and build succesfully.
I never had issues with spaces in `JAVA_HOME` and I always install it in `Program Files`.
So I am not sure if this is some issue of `Windows 7`.
If anyone could explain why this occurs I will mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Can you try with `C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`

Comment: As a rule, I never save java in a location that has spaces in the path.

Comment: @Chris When jdk gets installed in Windows, by default path is `C:\Program Files` and there is space in `Program Files` folder.

Comment: @Chris:Never had problem before

Comment: @Polppan: I always put my jdks in a folder `c:\Dev`.  I usually have more than one version of the jdk in `c:\Dev` too.  I guess I have been influenced by my experiences using Linux.